# How could I do a HDMI channel mapper?

Tags: arduino

I have two HDMI displays, and five sources. I want to map them programatically using an arduino e. g. I say I want the first input on the first output and the third input on the second output. And it should also be able to put the same input on both outputs.

The only solution that came in my mind is to split every single source with an HDMI splitter, and switch between them with an HDMI switcher, controlled by arduino via IR, but I hope there is a cheaper and nicer solution.

Comment: Hello tvili currently I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish—or how it relates to the Internet of Things. Please have a look at the [help], if you judge your question to be on-topic you should [edit] your question to clearly state your problem.